# Assigning variables to AJAX .get calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

Based on some great references on StackOverflow I know to use `$.when()` to trigger some event after a `$.get` request completes.

But what if the `$.get` is inside a for loop?

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
   $.get()...
}

$.when().done(function(a){
}
```

So I thought I would assign each variable to an array:

```
var d = Array(5);
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
   d[0] = $.get()...
}

$.when(d).done(function(a){
...
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Any alternatives to suggest? Or am I doing something close to correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not terrible clear what you're asking, but if you want to aggregate all the requests and execute a single callback when they have all completed, you'd do it like this:

Use `apply` on `$.when` with an array of requests

```
var requests = [];
for(var i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
  requests.push($.get(...));
}

$.when.apply(null,requests).then(function() { });
```

If the `.then` isn't firing, it's because one or more `$.get` requests have failed. Try this:

```
$.when
  .apply(null,requests)
  .then(
    function() { console.log('success'); },
    function() { console.log('at least one failed'); }
  );
```

Comment: I tried this. When you put `requests.push`, all the `$.get` requests fire. So all the requests are done by the time you get to the `$.when`, so the `.then` never fires.

Comment: @Rio - that's not how promises work. The `.then` fires when all the promises are resolved, regardless of if they are already resolved or will resolve at some point in the future. If the `.then` never fires, it's perhaps because not all of them resolved (maybe one or more of them failed?). Also, of course they make their requests as soon as you create them - when do you want them to make the request?

Comment: You're right. One of them failed. Is there a way to escape the failures and continue even if it does?

Comment: Yes, in your original `$.get` call you can catch an error and send back a resolved promise `$.get().then(function() { /* success */ },function() { /* fail */ return $.Deferred().resolve(someValue); });` Pre 1.8 jQuery versions require you to use `.pipe` instead of `.then`

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the done() within the for loop?

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
   $.get().when().done(function(a){
     ...
   }
}
```

or maybe more simply:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
   $.get( url, function(a){
      ...
   });
}
```

within this example, 'a' will be unique in each callback instance.

**UPDATE** based on comment:

```
var accumulate; //outside the loop

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
   $.get( url, function(a){
      accumulate += a;
   });
}
```

**UPDATE** for async http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.parallel

```
var myTasks = [];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
   myTasks.push( function( callback )
      {
         $.get( url, function(a){
           callback( null, a);
         });
      }
}
async.parallel( myTasks, function( err, resultsArray )
{
    // all done
    // aggregate the array as you wish.
});
```

Comment: Not quite; I need something that aggregates the data from all responses (all function(a)'s in each $.get).

Comment: If you try to retrieve `accumulate` after the for loop and the $.get request takes a long time, `accumulate` will be blank.

Comment: What?  You don't want to wait for your answer?!? For that I'd look at the async.js library.

Comment: I do want to wait for the answer from all the get requests. Your suggestion won't wait for all the answers, because the accumulate variable will accumulate asynchronously.

Comment: Oh I'll try your new suggestion.